# Binding свойства rectangle

Tags: wpf, binding, global-variables

Расскажите пожалуйста как можно было бы публичную переменную типа int привязать к свойству height у контрола Rectangle, ну в смысле чтобы когда я поменял значение переменной height сразу поменялся на значение переменной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding можно использовать только с [DependencyProperties](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level4/4_3.php), значит вам нужно реализовать нечто подобное и затем выполнить Binding.

Answer (score 0):

У `Rectangle` уже есть свойство зависимости. Если значение будет вводиться в `TextBox`, то код может выглядеть вот так:

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="_myTextBox"></TextBox>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="120" Height="100" Name="_myRectangle"></Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Binding binding = new Binding(); 

        binding.ElementName = "_myTextBox"; // элемент-источник

        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");// свойство элемента-источника
        _myRectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.HeightProperty, binding); // установка привязки для элемента-приемника
    }
}
```